# ADF-Azure Data factory multiple wild card filtering

Tags: file, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have a condition where i have more than 2 types of files which i have to filter out. I can filter out 1 type using wildcard, something like: *.csv but cant do something like *.xls, *.zip.

I have a pipeline which should convert csv, avro, dat files into .parquet format. But, folder also have .zip, excel, powerpoint files and i want them o be filtered out. Instead of using 3-4 activities i am finding if any way i can use (or) condition to filter out multiple extensions using wildcard option of data factory?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic content can't accept multiple `wildcards` or `Regular expression` based on my test.

[image]

You have to using multiple activities to match the different types of your files.Or you could consider a workaround that using LookUp activity+For-each Activity.

1.LookUp Activity loads all the file names from specific folder.(Child Item)

2.Check the file format in the for-each activity condition.(using [endswith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#endswith) built-in feature)

3.If the file format matches the filter condition, then go into the `True` branch and configure it as dynamic path of dataset in the copy activity.

Comment: Just a correction. LookUp Activity can't do that. Get MetaData activity can retrieve sub-folders and sub-files of a folder through its childItems property - however, not recursively. LookUp activity is used to read the content of a file or table - you can use it if you have a config file with paths.